# jQuery - Using Live to open a Window,and then close it?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Dialog box to all a user to click a project, that opens on click.... Here's the code:

```
$("#byproject").live("click", function() {
    $("#projectPicker").fadeIn();
    return false;
});
// Close the space dialog on selection
$(".projectSelect").live("click", function() {
    $("#projectPicker").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

This works very well to open the dialog box that is being position:absolute, next to the "select projects" button...

Problem here is that if the user clicks outside the box (ie they change their mind) the box doesn't close...

Is there some smart way I can say, when this thing is open, if the user clicks anywhere outside of the dialog box, close it?

Thanks

Comment: are you using the dialog from jquery ui? Does the background go black when you open it? If so you could attach an event on to that. Otherwise you could attach an event onto the body.

Comment: @Matt, I'm not using jquery Ui for this dialog

Comment: When the dialog box appears, you can add a "background div" to the page, spanning 100% height and 100% width. When the user clicks that "Background div," you can fadeOut. Personally, I would recommend doing it with the help of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach a click event to the document body that will close the window, and prevent propagation of the click event so click on the window will not close it. I wrote a similar answer to [a similar question 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/153047#153047) - not sure if it's similar enough to close this one.

```
$('body').click(function() {
  //Close window
});

$('#projectPicker').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

By the way, is there a reason you are using a live event on the links? at least the one with the id should probably use a regular click event.

Comment: Because you are not using jquery ui or anything that will pop up with a background this will probably be the easiest thing.

Comment: thanks but how do I enable this bind when the dialog I made is open? I don't want this bind always running? any idea how jquery ui dialog does it? Id love to use jquery ui dialog but I need absolute positioning.

Comment: You can add the click event on the body when the dialog opens and remove it using .unbind('click',...)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should suffice

```
$('*').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if($(this).is('#byproject')){       
             $("#projectPicker").fadeIn();
             return false;
        }else{
             $("#projectPicker").fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

so if the dialog is opened, any other element that is clicked on the page would close the dialog.

Comment: honestly i wouldn't bind everything just for something like this.

Comment: yea I guess. Eran's better. actually I wanted to delete this after I saw his. :p